# Search data using select tags with multiple option in php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I was trying to search data from database using multiple select tags on onchange select tags, I have four select tags with multiple select option. here is form

```html
<form method="GET" id="first_form" >
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Maintenance</label> 
         <select id="chkveg" name="maintenance[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="21">Low</option>
            <option value="23">Medium</option> 
         </select>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />  
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Lighting </label>
         <select id="chkveg1" name="lighting[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="24">indoors: iow light</option>
            <option value="25">indoors: medium light</option> 
         </select>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="btnget1" value="Get Selected Values" /> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Shade </label><br/>
         <select id="chkveg2" name="shade[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="30">Low</option>
            <option value="31">Medium</option> 
         </select>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="btnget2" value="Get Selected Values" /> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">   
         <label>Other</label><br/>
         <select id="chkveg3" name="other[]" multiple="multiple"> 
           <option value="40">Low</option>
           <option value="41">Medium</option> 
         </select> 
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<div class="col-md-3" id="form-content"> 
  </div>
```

and my database table structure  is 
[image]
 search criteria is "If I select multiple options from one select tag, It should search using **OR** operator and If i select a option from second select tag, It should search using **AND** operator."

For example : In above form,If i select two option from maintenance tag, search using OR operator with one pl_maintenance_search column, If i select one option from lighting select tag, search using AND between pl_maintenance_search and pl_lighting_search. and same with other select tags.
I am submitting this form using this script

```js
$("form select").on('change', function () { 
 var dataString = $("#chkveg, #chkveg1, #chkveg2, #chkveg3").serialize();
    $.ajax({
   url: 'ajax_file.php',
   type: 'GET',
  data: dataString, 
          dataType: 'html'
         })
    .done(function(data){
      $('#form-content').html(data);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...'); 
    });
    
});
```

and here is my `ajax_file.php` code

```html
$operator='OR';
$all_array = $_GET; 
$unque_array = array(); 
$count=0;
foreach ($all_array as $main_key => $value )
{
    if($main_key)
    {
       $count++; 
    }
    if($count>1){  $operator='AND'; }          
 foreach ($value as $r_value)
 {       
     $single = $r_value;                     
     $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pl_details WHERE pl_maintenance_search LIKE ? $operator pl_lighting_search LIKE ? $operator  pl_shade_search LIKE ? $operator  pl_other_search LIKE ?  ";
  $params = array("%$single%", "%$single%", "%$single%", "%$single%" );
  $select_maint_plants = $con->prepare($query);
  $select_maint_plants->execute($params);
        
     while($fetch_light_plants = $select_maint_plants->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   if(!in_array($fetch_light_plants['id'], $unque_array))
   {
    echo $fetch_light_plants['pl_name'];  echo '<br/>';
   }
   $unque_array[]= $fetch_light_plants['id'];
  }//End while loop     
        }//End foreach loop
}//End foreach loop
```

Above code is working with only single select tag, and not with others tag.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: How looks query with others tag? Show us.

Comment: If I select other select tags it will search based on latest single selected tag

Comment: Yes, but you said, that problem is, with multiple tags - show how looks like query in that case.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pl_details WHERE pl_maintenance_search LIKE ? AND pl_lighting_search LIKE ? AND  pl_shade_search LIKE ? AND  pl_other_search LIKE ?  ";

Comment: I thought about rewriting your php code to give you a good query. But you have a big database structure problem. Because the pl_something_search field contain comma seperated values. That would make a query extremly complicated. Image you have *24,25,26* in the field and you want to search for 23 or 24. With a good structure you could just use *IN (23,24)*. But with your structure you need to check for *23* or *23,%* or *%,23,%* or *%,23* - and repeat that for 24.

Comment: Aks them? Doubt they will answer and tell you details. The problem lies in your database structure - Normalization is a keyword here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization#246751 And do not put multiple values into one field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699534/mysql-table-with-multiple-values-in-one-field#9699957